# Get friendly Url

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have started using Url Rewrite in asp.net.

I used to have a QueryString that looked like this

***localhost/Booking.aspx?Id=ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1***

In C# I know how to get the querystring for Id like this

```
if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null && Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["Id"]) != Guid.Empty)
{
    Guid Id = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
}
```

Know I changed to used SEO so the url looks like this

***localhost/Booking/ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1***

How can I get the value **ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1** in c#?

Comment: You need to same, the format is changed but querystring value not changed.Please take look for more way http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574956/How-to-get-URL-and-QueryString-value-in-an-ASP-NET

Comment: Shoit should be **boldGuid Id = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["Booking"]);** to get the value ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1?